# How do I stop Skype playing my own sound back to me?

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, logitech-headset

I just got a new headset and when making a call, Skype plays my own voice in the headset. It's not echo, there's no delay, and the voice is crystal clear. I believe this is to help people not shout, but I don't need it and I find it distracting. It wasn't happening with my previous headset.

My new headset is a Logitech Pro X Wireless, I'm running Logitech G Hub, on Windows 10 and using the Skype that comes with Windows 10. I searched for an option to stop this on Skype, G Hub and Windows but I couldn't find it. Any ideas where it is?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your Skype sound settings

Answer (score 0):

> My new headset is a Logitech Pro X Wireless, I'm running Logitech G Hub, on Windows 10 and using the Skype that comes with Windows 10.

Based on [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/SbqmmfoCjW8), it sounds like you may need to adjust the "Sidetone" settings in Logitech G Hub. From the video:

1. Bring up Logitech G Hub.
2. Click the icon for the headset.
3. On the left-hand side of the new Logitech G Hub window, click the "Acoustics" (middle Speaker) icon.
4. In the upper left-hand corner, adjust the "Sidetone" slider down to e.g. 0.

Answer (score -1):

Try disable sidetone feature

Open Logitech G Hub
Select your Logitech Pro X Wireless headset
Click on "Equalizer"
Scroll to the "Sidetone" section and & click toggle switch to turn it off.

If you are still hearing your own voice in the headset you may need to adjust the settings in Skype

Open Skype

open "Settings" from the dropdown menu.
Click on "Audio & Video" .
Under "Speakers," make sure your Logitech Pro X Wireless is as playback device.
Under "Microphone," make sure Pro X Wireless is as recording device.
Make sure that the "Automatically adjust microphone settings" option is turned off.